# mean and standard deviation from rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1)

Tags: self-study, sampling, standard-deviation, mean

I am trying to figure out a good way to find mean and standard deviation from sampling rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1) 1,000 times.

I thought about using a for loop and combining the result of rnorm as a list, but mean() only takes numeric or logical.

Any pointers are appreciated, since I am just starting to learn R.

To clarify, I am trying to ask for help on R code to do what is in the first line. As of now, it has been resolved, but people in the comments asked me to make my question more clear.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you're interested in generating 5,000 samples from a standard normal distribution then just use `rnorm(5000)` rather than taking 5 samples 1,000 times.  Then take the mean and standard deviation of your result, but I don't suspect you'll be surprised by what you get.

Comment: @dsaxton. This is a physics laboratory question. I was asked to sample this distribution once and then try it 1000 times. Each time, I am supposed to think about whether or not the results are what I expect. When I ran the distribution once, the results were not what I expect, but when I sampled the distribution 1000 times, the answers were much close to what I expect.

Comment: Are you asking for help w/ R code, for understanding sampling distributions, something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung. Thank you for the link. I have made the updates.

Comment: @user26658 Ok, apparently it's just a matter of increasing the sample size, so just use `rnorm(n)` for different values of `n`.  I guess your teacher wants you to understand things like the law of large numbers.

Comment: @dsaxton. I assumed that was what they were going for. The subsequent question is on law of large numbers and has exponentially distributed numbers. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @user26658 No problem.  BTW, the reason you don't need to set the values of `mean` and `sd` is that the default values are zero and one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replicate` to run a command multiple times.

```
res <- replicate(1000, rnorm(5, mean = 0, sd = 1))
mean(res)
sd(res)
```

You can also use the result to calculate the mean of the 1000 means:

```
mean(colMeans(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
    data = matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow = 5) #each column is a sample with n=5
    #the expected value of the mean ~0
    mean(apply(data, 2, mean))
    hist(apply(data, 2, mean))
    #the standard error of the mean ~1/sqrt(5) = 0.4472136
    sd(apply(data, 2, sd))
    hist(apply(data, 2, sd))
    #the mean of all data ~0
    mean(data)
    #the standard deviation of all data ~1
    sd(data)
```